# Multi-release jar files without multiple sets of source code

Tags: java, jar, java-9, multi-release-jar

I want to create a multi-release JAR file for a library. I will build the MRJAR using maven - and initially it will contain Java 8 and Java 9 class files.

BUT - I do not want to maintain two separate sets of source code (e.g. in `src/main/java-8` and `src/main/java-9`). Is it possible to have all of the Java-9 files in e.g. `src/main/java` and only the ones *which differ* in e.g. `src/main/java-8` ?

Ideally, the full source code would then be organized as:

```
+ pom.xml
+ src
  + main
    + java
      <full java-9 source code>
    + java-8
      <overriding .java files which can only be compiled with java-8>
```

Comment: Did you read the Maven document about handling Multi Release jar files? A simple web search for [`maven multi-release jar`](https://www.google.com/search?q=maven+multi-release+jar) lead right there: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/multirelease.html. --- The search also found many good articles on the subject.

Comment: @Andreas - yes I did, mr. Grumpy. But the article is all about .class files. Not .java files.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#multi-release-jar-files

Comment: Doesn’t sound like a useful setup for multi-release jar. In order to use your software under Java 8, *all* needed classes must be available in a Java 8 compatible way. So the natural setup would be to have a full java-8 source code folder and a patch folder containing overriding files using java-9 features. It would match the way, the resulting jar is organized, all classes be put into the root (java-8 compatible) and a version specific folder containing the overriding classes for java-9+. I suggest tagging the question with `[maven]` to attract the experts to tell you how to do it with maven.

Comment: Thanks @Holger - I will try to pursue this.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not want to maintain two separate sets of source code

You have to, so you can compile the Java 8 files separately from the Java 9 files.

Implied in the question (the way I read it), but not explicitly stated, is that you have two copies of the files that *don't differ*. You certainly don't need that.

> Is it possible to have all of the Java-9 files in e.g. src/main/java and only the ones which differ in e.g. src/main/java-8 ?

That wouldn't make any sense, because all the files that don't differ must be Java 8 files, not Java 9 files.

Do the opposite.